# builtins.ImportError: No module named:

Tags: python, canvas

I've been trying to open a gaming window in Wing IDE 101.6.0 
But I seem to have trouble with the imported  module. I am unable to recall what function will help me complete my task. I've tried 'cso' and 'StartPy' but neither will work when I debug my code.

All I get is builtins.ImportError: No module named 'cso'
or builtins.ImportError: No module named 'StartPy'.
I don't know if there is another alternative that will help.
Here is my basic code:
Anything will help

```
from StartPy import *
WIDTH= 800
HEIGHT= 800
ONE_SECOND=1000

setColor(BLACK)
setWidth(WIDTH)
setHeight(HEIGHT)
setCaption("CANVAS")


start()

stop()
```

Comment: `from StartPy import *` is not good at all, since your namespace is now polluted. Try `import StartPy` and then use `StartPy.setColor` etc. It's probably futile to debug until you do that. If `StartPy` is too much to type each time, `import StartPy as sp` and then use `sp.setColor`.

Comment: Also StartPy is not defined as this import only import all the contents, not the module itself

Comment: Also, what is `BLACK`?

Comment: I can't find any python gaming api packages by either name StartPy or cso..do you have either of those modules in your workspace?